# How to pivot strings dynamically

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, pivot

My workplace has implemented an Oracle Exadata server to run behind our SAS installation. I'm in the process of converting my SAS script to run in this Oracle environment using SQL passthrough. I cannot seem to come up with a pivot that gives me the same results as my SAS "PROC TRANSPOSE"

Here is my proc from SAS

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA=WORK.ROW_LEVEL_DATA OUT=WORK.PIVOT_DATA (DROP= _NAME_ _LABEL_) PREFIX=ORDR;
  BY GROUPKEY;
  ID ORDR_NUM;
  VAR STRING_VAL;
RUN;
```

My data is setup so that each STRING_VAL is numbered sequentially to 25. Currently, SAS will pivot by the GROUPKEY and create a columns ORDR1, ORDR2, ORDR3, etc all the way up to 25. Each STRING_VAL is placed in the appropriately numbered column.

This is the result I'm trying to recreate using passthrough SQL.

```
GROUPKEY     ORDR1     ORDR2    ORDR3
123456       AAAAA     BBBBB    CCCCC
654645       AAAAA
759876       BBBBB     CCCCC
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT: I processed just over 1B records using the SAS PROC which produced 98.6M transposed records in 16 minutes. It's an acceptable amount of time but I'm curious if there is a better method using passthrough SQL.**

Comment: Are you happy if the query always returns a result set with columns `ORDR1` through `ORDR25` regardless of whether there are actually 25 values in for any `GROUPKEY`?  If I follow your SAS code, you're sorting by `ordr_num` but displaying `string_val`, right?  So the fact that your sample happens to be sorted alphabetically by `string_val` is coincidence (or a side effect of sorting by `ordr_num`)?

Comment: Yes I would be happy with that. Typically, the query will always generate records that have 25 values. The dataset I'm using could exceed 50 values at times. During my data prep, I'm deleting anything above 25 since it would increase the size of the entire SAS dataset exponentially. Also the purpose of this dataset is general analysis so the deleted values don't contribute more than 0.001%. The sort order is important. I'm using it to aggregate the records for analysis purposes (volumes, etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in pure SQL with something along the lines of:

- Use a subquery to assign numbers to each order (row_number if they're unique, dense_rank if they aren't), partitioned by group
- Pivot the result of this

Which gives:

```
create table t (
  groupkey integer,
  ordr_num varchar2(10)
);

insert into t values ( 123456, 'AAAAA' );
insert into t values ( 123456, 'BBBBB' );
insert into t values ( 123456, 'CCCCC' );
insert into t values ( 654645, 'AAAAA' );
insert into t values ( 759876, 'BBBBB' );
insert into t values ( 759876, 'CCCCC' );

with ranks as ( 
  select t.*, 
         dense_rank() over (
           partition by groupkey
           order by ordr_num
         ) rn
  from   t
)
  select * from ranks
  pivot (
    min ( ordr_num ) for rn in (
      1 ord1, 2 ord2, 3 ord3 -- etc. up to ord25
    )
  );

GROUPKEY    ORD1     ORD2      ORD3     
     123456 AAAAA    BBBBB     CCCCC     
     654645 AAAAA    <null>    <null>    
     759876 BBBBB    CCCCC     <null>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've already numbered the orders. I need to create a table with the transposed results. I'll give it a try and report back.

Comment: Method worked well. It produced the table in under 8 minutes. The only issue I found was that I was not able to select the fields I needed. The table I'm pulling those variables from has more than just `groupkey`, `ordr_num` and `rn`. I had to create a separate table with only those variables. Likely a "me" issue because I'm not familiar with the pivot function though. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool, thanks. You should be able to get the other columns in the same query, not sure how this maps to what you're doing. Be aware that columns in the subquery not in the `pivot` clause form an implicit `group by`. So you could end up with more than one row for each groupkey.